# React native TextInput placeholder: initial position is wrong in Android

Tags: android, react-native

I have a TextInput with the below style in my code. The TextInput and a button is inside a view, with flex 85 and 15 respectively, and I've set padding: 10, but initially the placeholder touches the left border. If I type something, the text comes in right position and the placeholder too, i.e. after clearing the text.

The problem is in Android only.

[Screenshot attached.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Stn3z.jpg)

```
textInput: {
width: '100%',
marginHorizontal: 0,
height: 41,
color: 'black',
padding: 10,
borderWidth: 1,
borderColor: 'grey',
borderRadius: 5,
fontSize: 16,
}
addEmailRow: {
flexDirection: 'row',
width: '100%',
alignSelf: 'stretch',
height: 60,
textAlign: 'center',
paddingTop: 10,
paddingHorizontal: 20,
backgroundColor: 'grey',
},
addEmailInput: {
flex: 85,
height: '100%',
},
addEmailButton: {
flex: 15,
height: '100%',
alignContent: 'center',
alignItems: 'center',
alignSelf: 'center',
}

<View style={styles.addEmailRow}>
                    <View style={styles.addEmailInput}>
                      <TextInput
                        style={styles.textInput}
                        placeholder={'Email'}
                        keyboardType={'email-address'}
                        autoCapitalize={'none'}
                        value={emailAddress}
                      />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.addEmailButton}>
                      <TouchableOpacity
                        style={styles.addButton}
                        activeOpacity={0.5}
                        onPress={addEmailButtonTapped}>
                        <Image
                          source={require('../../Assets/add-circle-icn.png')}
                        />
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                  </View>
```

I've tried resetting padding, padding horizontal, padding left etc, but didn't work.

Comment: It's working as expected for me. Here's a [Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@kartikeyvaish/textinput-so) to try. Tested for Android, iOS and Web

Comment: Yes right , on Snack, it works as expected. Did you try it on emulator ? or real device ? the issue exists on both emulator & android phone.

Comment: Yes I tested this on iPhone 13. Here's a [Screen Recording](https://res.cloudinary.com/kartikeyvaish/video/upload/v1681156382/StackOverflow/RPReplay_Final1681156292_qghajq.mp4) for the Snack.

Comment: on iPhone it is Ok, the issue is in Android only. Please check on Android emulator.

Comment: Yes, its working perfectly fine on Android Emulator too. Try on Snack's Android emulator. I would suggest you to create a new AVD and then run your app on it.

Comment: any update on this one ? Got the same issue